# Android Beam: keep pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc, android-beam

as far as I've read, android beam uses NFC to establish a BluetoothConnection, then transfers data via bluetooth. It also pairs the devices if necessary. But only until the transfer is complete, then unpairs them automatically.

I want to pair the devices via beam, then keep the pairing alive and also the bluetooth adapter on.

I've found nothing to do this, is this possible at all?